# JSF null pointer exception

Tags: jsf

```
    <pre><h:form>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputLabel value="Username: " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText value="#{user.username}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Password: " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{user.doLogin()}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</pre>
```

COuld someone explain my why this causes the exception? This is my first JSF application.

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at userSession.getUsername(userSession.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

Comment: There's an error in the `userSession#getUsername` method. Please provide the managed bean code in order to get better help. Also, specify if you're using JSF 1.x or JSF 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Check your line 45 of `getUserName` method. Probably a parameter of that method has a `null` reference, which. means a setter gives a null. Try also to obtain your input text in `doLogin()` method

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
Map<String, String> parameterMap = (Map<String, String>) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
username=parameterMap.get("id_of_your_inputfield");
```